# Type converter for List of objects in room db

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to insert in my room database, a list of employees for every Task. I am getting this error :

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it. private final
>   java.util.List assignees = null;

How can I create a type converter for a List??

```
 @Entity(tableName = "Task",
     foreignKeys = [(
            ForeignKey(entity = IssueType::class,
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                    parentColumns = ["id"],
                    childColumns = ["typeId"]
            )),
        (ForeignKey(entity = Location::class,
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                parentColumns = ["id"],
                childColumns = ["locationId"]))
    ])
 data class Task(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val typeId: Id,
    val locationId: Id,
    val priority: Priority,
    val deadline: Date,
    val assignees: List<Employee>,
    val description: String,
    val taskState: TaskState
 )
```

Comment: You don't. You remove `assignees` from `Task`. You query the DAO for `Employee` to get the employees for a `Task`. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data.html#understand-no-object-references.

Comment: yes but every task has different employees which I select. And employees could have many tasks.

Comment: Maybe start with [relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity(tableName = "EmployeeTask",
            primaryKeys = arrayOf("employeeId", "taskId"),
            foreignKeys = arrayOf(
                    ForeignKey(entity = Employee::class,
                            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                            childColumns = arrayOf("employeeId")),
                    ForeignKey(entity = Task::class,
                            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                            childColumns = arrayOf("taskId"))
            )
    )
    data class EmployeeIssue(val employeeId: Id,
                             val taskId: Id)



     @Dao
        interface EmployeeWithTaskDao {
            @Insert
            fun insert(employedTask: EmployeeTask)

            @Query("""
                   SELECT * FROM Task
                   INNER JOIN EmployeeTask
                   ON Task.id=EmployeeTask.taskId
                   WHERE EmployeeTask.employeeId=:employeeId
                   """)
            fun getTasksForEmployees(employeeId: Int): Array<Task>

            @Query("""
                   SELECT * FROM employee
                   INNER JOIN EmployeeTask
                   ON EMPLOYEE.id=EmployeeTask.employeeId
                   WHERE EmployeeTask.taskId=:taskId
                   """)
            fun getEmployeesForTask(taskId: Int): Array<Employee>
        }
```

Comment: If `Employee` is another entity, that's not how you do it. You'd have to model the relations properly.

Comment: Should I remove List<Employee> from Task?

Comment: Yes. That might be the best. You could create another model which holds these relations and query it properly as well.

Comment: what do you mean about another model? Isn't the current models enough??

Answer (score 0):

You should create a type converter and annotate your list with

> @TypeConverters(DataConverter::class)  val assignees: List

so your data class will look like this...

```
data class Task(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int,
val typeId: Id,
val locationId: Id,
val priority: Priority,
val deadline: Date,
@TypeConverters(DataConverter::class) val assignees: List<Employee>,
val description: String,
val taskState: TaskState
)
```

create a DataConverter class that will look

```
class DataConverter {
@TypeConverter
fun fromProductList(employeeList: List<Employee>): String? {
    if (employeeList == null) {
        return null
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    val type =
        object : TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {}.type
    return gson.toJson(employeeList, type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun toProductList(employeeListString: String?): List<Employee>? {
    if (employeeListString == null) {
        return null
    }
    val gson = Gson()
    val type =
        object : TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {}.type
    return gson.fromJson(employeeListString, type)
}
}
```